# How to compare 2 elements inside 2 arrays? I would use the below its only for when comparing to a single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is not quite the function for it. How can you Loop thru each array to compare values? Or should these data structures be different? Or transformed first?

Here's the data being compared. Goal is to compare `userID` with `DocumentID`.

```
const videos = 
  [ { userID: '5lyU0TCyqRcTD3y7Rs2FGV8h2Sd2', name: 'Wedge Antilles',  faction: 'Rebels' } 
  , { userID: '8',                            name: 'Ciena Ree',       faction: 'Empire' } 
  , { userID: '40',                           name: 'userIDen Versio', faction: 'Empire' } 
  , { userID: '66',                           name: 'Thane Kyrell',    faction: 'Rebels' } 
  ] 
 
const blocked = 
  [ { id:  2, name: 'Wedge Antilles', documentID: '5lyU0TCyqRcTD3y7Rs2FGV8h2Sd2' } 
  , { id:  8, name: 'Ciena Ree',      documentID: 'Empire'                       } 
  , { id: 40, name: 'Iden Versio',    documentID: 'Empire'                       } 
  , { id: 66, name: 'Thane Kyrell',   documentID: 'Rebels'                       } 
  ] 
var result = videos.filter(function(videos, index) { 
  return videos["userID"] === blocked.documentID 
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary with `userID` as the key? Same for `blocked`, why don't you use a dict for that as well?

Comment: what result do you expect from the (given) data?

Comment: How are userID and documentID related? In the example arrays you give `5lyU0TCyqRcTD3y7Rs2FGV8h2Sd2` being the same for one of the userID and documentID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have different ways to do this. For example, you can use javascript functions [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the following way:

```
var blockedIds = blocked.map(function(blockedItem, index) {
  return blockedItem.documentID;
});
var result = videos
  .filter(function(videos, index) {
    return blockedIds.includes(videos["userID"]);
  });
```

But you know that this will execute the operation in time O(nxm) (where n is the size of the first array and m is the size of the second one).

Answer (score 0):

I would transform these blocked into an object/map, and then try to filter through it.

```
const bMap = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(blocked).map(item => [item.documentID, item]))

// then
var result = videos.filter((videos) => bMap[videos.userID])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it via below steps :

- Fetch `documentID` using `Array.map()` method in a `separate` array as we are going to compare only documentID with the userID.
- Now using `Array.filter()` method, we can compare the videos array with the `documentIDArray` to filtered out the matched results.

**Demo :**

```js
const videos = [{
  userID: '5lyU0TCyqRcTD3y7Rs2FGV8h2Sd2',
  name: 'Wedge Antilles',
  faction: 'Rebels'
}, {
  userID: '8',
  name: 'Ciena Ree',
  faction: 'Empire'
}, {
  userID: '40',
  name: 'userIDen Versio',
  faction: 'Empire'
}, {
  userID: '66',
  name: 'Thane Kyrell',
  faction: 'Rebels'
}]; 

const blocked = [{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Wedge Antilles',
  documentID: '5lyU0TCyqRcTD3y7Rs2FGV8h2Sd2'
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: 'Ciena Ree',
  documentID: 'Empire'
}, {
  id: 40,
  name: 'Iden Versio',
  documentID: 'Empire'
}, {
  id: 66,
  name: 'Thane Kyrell',
  documentID: 'Rebels'
}];

// Fetch documentID using Array.map() method in a seperate array as we are going to compare only documentID with the userID.
const documentIDArray = blocked.map((obj) => obj.documentID);

// Now using Array.filter() method, we can compare the videos array with the documentIDArray to filtered out the matched results.
var result = videos.filter(video => documentIDArray.includes(video['userID']));

console.log(result);
```